# How to query the position of a process instance?

Tags: java, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

I want to get the current position of a single instance in my process. Is it possible to get the name of the activity additionaly to the id as return value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the current position of your process instance using the following code, which will also give you the name of the activity(ies) when the process waits in multiple position.

```
package org.camunda.bpm;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance;
import org.camunda.bpm.model.bpmn.BpmnModelInstance;
import org.camunda.bpm.model.xml.instance.ModelElementInstance;

public class AllActiveActivities {

  public Map<String, String> getAllActiveActivities(String processInstanceId) {
    // get engine services
    ProcessEngine processEngine = BpmPlatform.getDefaultProcessEngine()
    RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();

    // get the process instance
    ProcessInstance processInstance =
        runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
            .singleResult();

    HashMap<String, String> activityNameByActivityId = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // get all active activities of the process instance
    List<String> activeActivityIds =
        runtimeService.getActiveActivityIds(processInstance.getId());

    // get bpmn model of the process instance
    BpmnModelInstance bpmnModelInstance =
        repositoryService.getBpmnModelInstance(processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());

    for (String activeActivityId : activeActivityIds) {
      // get the speaking name of each activity in the diagram
      ModelElementInstance modelElementById =
          bpmnModelInstance.getModelElementById(activeActivityId);
      String activityName = modelElementById.getAttributeValue("name");

      activityNameByActivityId.put(activeActivityId, activityName);
    }

    // map contains now all active activities
    return activityNameByActivityId;
  }

}
```